# Oracle DB performance: view vs table

Tags: sql, oracle, view, database-performance, sql-view

I have created a table that is a join of 3-4 other tables. The field values in the original source tables from which this table was created DO change, but rarely.

Updating or recreating the table takes about 30 mins-1 hour, and then some reports are run against it. However, this requires keeping track of any changes from the original source tables.

If, instead, I run reports off a VIEW, I know with 100% certainty that all the field values are correct - but will my SELECT performance suffer and become slower due to the view 'going back and fetching' values each time?

In this case, speed is on the same level of importance of accuracy, and my ultimate question is ***whether to use a view or a table***. Thank you to anyone who's taken the time to read this!

Comment: I want to make sure I understand you here. You have a table that is the result of a query between 4 tables? So it's like a `SELECT INTO` query and this process takes 30 - 60 minutes to run?

Comment: If your source tables change, then your view has to change. So I don't see what this buys you?

Comment: As I know, the view is slower than the table because when you select a view, database always executes the query of that view. Maybe you should take the partial update on your table when the original source tables are updated instead of recreating it.

Comment: How about materialized views?

Comment: @KonstantinSorokin I think materialized views is exactly what i want here! Thank you